# Purchase : AcquireActivity Intent denied

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-billing

So i set up my environment for testing Android In-App billing.

- My application Key is stored as a raw string to avoid any issue for now
- My application has the **`BILLING`** permission
- My application is published in **Closed Beta**
- All my products (none are subscriptions) are tagged as **`ACTIVE`**
- My Activity (the one which makes the call to **Billing** features) overrides `onActivityResult`
- I use [IABv3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) to implement In-App Billing
- I can successfully get the `SkuDetails` of my products.

---

**The issue is upon a call to :`bp.purchase(activity, productId);` (ie starting a purchaseFlow), I get the following logs :**

---

**ActivityManager**: START u0 {*act*=com.google.android.finsky.ACQUIRE *dat*=iabData:inapp:`my.package`:`productId` *pkg*=com.android.vending *cmp*=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.billing.acquire.AcquireActivity (has extras)} from uid 10131 on display 0

**D/com.android.server.am.ExtraActivityManagerService**: MIUILOG- **Permission Denied Activity** : Intent { *act*=com.google.android.finsky.ACQUIRE *dat*=iabData:inapp:`my.package`:`productId` *pkg*=com.android.vending *cmp*=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.billing.acquire.AcquireActivity (has extras) } *pkg* : com.android.vending *uid* : 10131 *tuid* : 10170

---

From what I see, everything works well until the PurchaseFlow starts (ie when the `AcquireActivity` `Intent` is launched). So the permisson is `DENIED` but I can't understand why or how to fix it as the only mandatory permission is `BILLING` and it is enabled.

*Note :* As **IAB** can only be tested through a real device, it may be an issue with `MIUI` but I don't own any other device so I can't test if this is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just turn on the "Start in background" permission for "Google Play Store"**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After testing on another phone, thanks to a friend, it is indeed a `MIUI`related issue.

Porbably because the application s debuggable or not published at a production stage on the `Google Play Store`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was very hard to find.
Redmi 4A, Android 7, MIUI 10.2.3. Main activity for app in `debug` version could not start to foreground from service. There was `MIUILOG- Permission Denied Activity` error in `logcat`. Rebuilding this app in `release` version fixed the problem.