# Could not start activity from service (com.android.server.am.ExtraActivityManagerService: MIUILOG- Permission Denied Activity)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, xiaomi, miui

Device: Xiaomi Redmi 4A, Android 7, MIUI 10.

Code for running activity from service:

```
String pkgName = context.getPackageName();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, main_activity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
intent.setPackage(pkgName);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(pkgName, main_activity.class.getName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

does not do anything. In `logcat` there are following messages:

```
11-25 23:56:57.697 10012 10094 I Timeline: Timeline: 
Activity_launch_request time:191155603 intent:Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
flg=0x10100000 pkg=com.qwe7002.telegram_sms cmp=com.qwe7002.telegram_sms/.main_activity }
11-25 23:56:57.699  1416  7227 I ActivityManager: 
START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
flg=0x10100000 pkg=com.qwe7002.telegram_sms cmp=com.qwe7002.telegram_sms/.main_activity} 
from uid 10340 on display 0
11-25 23:56:57.699  1416  7227 
D com.android.server.am.ExtraActivityManagerService: MIUILOG- Permission Denied Activity : Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 
pkg=com.qwe7002.telegram_sms cmp=com.qwe7002.telegram_sms/.main_activity } 
pkg : com.qwe7002.telegram_sms uid : 10340 tuid : 10020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that helped to me:

- Building apk in `release` version, not in `debug` version.

As turned out MIUI blocks starting activities from service for `debug` applications.

There are recommendations ( [Just turn on the "Start in background" permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49378037/1455694), [Manually enable background pop-up permission](https://www.pudn.com/news/62577457bd8c6f2306c7a0c4.html) ) to give to the app `Start in foreground`,  `Display pop-up window` permissions. But this does not change anything in my case.

---

Related questions:

- [MIUI - Permission denied while trying to start ACTION_SEND / ACTION_VIEW intent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65086160/1455694)
- [Start Activity from Service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3606596/1455694)
- [How to call an activity from service with Notification Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8733103/1455694)

Comment: Pretty sure this has nothing to do with release vs debug. I was seeing the same thing in a debug build, then did a release build and nothing changed.